# Create an index for json_array_elements in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I need to create an index from a query that uses `json_array_elements()`

```
SELECT *, json_array_elements(nested_json_as_text::json) as elements FROM my_table
```

Since the json contains multiple elements, the result is that the original index is now duplicated across rows and no longer unique.

I am not very familiar with creating indices and want to avoid doing anything destructive. What is the best way to create a column of unique integers for this case?

Answer (score 1):

Found an answer:

```
SELECT *, json_array_elements(nested_json_as_text::json) as elements, row_number() over () as my_index FROM my_table
```